# Running external python in Golang, Catching continuous exec.Command Stdout

Tags: go

So my go script will call an external python like this

```
cmd = exec.Command("python","game.py")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
go func(){
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil{
    panic(err)
    }
}()
```

It runs my python script concurrently which is awesome.
But now the problem is, my python script will run infinitely and it will print out some information from time to time. I want to "catch" these Stdout and print them out on my golang terminal. How do I do it concurrently (without waiting my python script to exit)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `cmd.Start()` and `cmd.Wait()` instead of `cmd.Run()`.

https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run

> Run starts the specified command and waits for it to complete.
>
> Start starts the specified command but does not wait for it to complete.
>
> Wait waits for the command to exit. It must have been started by Start.

And if you want to capture stdout/stderr concurrently, use `cmd.StdoutPipe()` / `cmd.StderrPipe()` and read it by `bufio.NewScanner()`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "game.py")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go copyOutput(stdout)
    go copyOutput(stderr)
    cmd.Wait()
}

func copyOutput(r io.Reader) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

The following is a sample python code for reproducing real-time output. The stdout may be buffered in Python. Explicit flush may be required.

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    print "Hello"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks! However this still doesn't help with capturing standard output of the cmd.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. if you want to capture stdout concurrently, how about cmd.StdoutPipe()?

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. I tried the new code but the code block at 
    for scanner.Scan()
and will not readline until my python script exit.

Comment: I don't know about the implementation of `game.py` , but stdout may be bufferd inside Python. How about explicitly specifying `sys.stdout.flush()` in Python?

Comment: Congrats. I added the sample reproduction python code to the answer.

Comment: Is this correct? Because you do not wait for copying goroutines to finish before calling `cmd.Wait` as it is required by in documentation: "It is thus incorrect to call Wait before all reads from the pipe have completed."

Answer (score 1):

You can use add the flag `-u` to turn off buffering,

```
cmd := exec.Command("python", "-u", "game.py")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

https://bugs.python.org/issue526382

Answer (score 1):

If you want to capture stdout and stderr concurrently, indeed you need to use `cmd.StdoutPipe()`, `cmd.StderrPipe()`, `cmd.Start()` and `cmd.Wait()`.

But as mentioned in the documentation (https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.StdoutPipe):

> It is thus incorrect to call Wait before all reads from the pipe have completed.

You'll need to wait for you goroutines to finish before calling `cmd.Wait()` (see the following thread: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/38268)