# Print the console log to the screen of a webpage continuously using Go Routines

Tags: go

I got the go routine below to work but the problem is that it prints to the console instead of to the screen. My idea is to have a running log of what commands or output is happening in a script show on a webpage where it can be watched in real time. Using fmt.Fprint doesn't do the trick. All that happens is that my webpage will never fully load. Help please?

[Running external python in Golang, Catching continuous exec.Command Stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41415337/running-external-python-in-golang-catching-continuous-exec-command-stdout)

go code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
    "os/exec"
    "io"
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    s := r.PathPrefix("/api/").Subrouter()
    s.HandleFunc("/export", export).Methods("GET")
    http.Handle("/", r)
    log.Panic(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}

func export(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "game.py")
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go copyOutput(stdout)
    go copyOutput(stderr)
    cmd.Wait()
}

func copyOutput(r io.Reader, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Fprint(w, scanner.Text()) //line I expect to print to the screen, but doesn't
    }
}
```

python script

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    print "Hello"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

There's a lot more to the site so I know the route is configured correctly because printing to the screen works when I'm not using the go routine'

UPDATE:

Here is my new update function which prints to the screen, but only after the entire script has ran, not as it goes

```
func export(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "game.py")
    cmd.Stdout = w
    cmd.Start()
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

I believe I may still need a go routine in order to get it to print as I go, but putting cmd.Start and/or cmd.Wait in one doesn't work

UPDATE:

So even with everything given, I have not been able to get having the outputs show on a browser as they are ran working. It simply locks up the browser, even with the headers and flush. I will hopefully have time to give a complete, working answer to this but for now, the code above prints the code to the browser correctly after it has ran. I found a repo that I think may be what I'm looking for and maybe it will help others who come across this question as well.

https://github.com/yudai/gotty

Comment: It's not that simple. You'll need to use something like AJAX polling or WebSockets to stream data to the browser, and some JavaScript to continuously update the DOM.

Comment: I can't see anything here that can write the response of a request to web page

Comment: Please fix your example; it doesn't compile as it is now. You may have to call w.Flush every now and then to send output down the wire, but if the browser renders anything before the response is complete depends on the browser (curl should work though). Also, you can simply assign w to cmd.Stdout and cmd.Stderr; no need for the copyOutput goroutines.

Comment: @Peter I will try w.Flush and how do I assign w to cmd.Stdout? As far as it not compiling, my bad, I will fix that too. This is for my company so I tried to grab the code relevant to my problem only

Comment: cmd.Stdout is an io.Writer, so assignment is trivial: https://play.golang.org/p/eoc4m_WKz3j

Comment: On second thought, depending on how you want to flush, you may have to keep the pipes. Flushing periodically doesn't need it, but flushing after N lines does.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the assign w. The problem is that I want it to write as it goes

Comment: Hi @coco: how about this example using gorilla/websocket library
https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/command

Comment: Assigning w to Stdout is the same as your goroutines, except not line buffered (it's not buffered *at all*). It says "hey, cmd, write your output directly to the ResponseWriter".

Comment: Wouldn't assigning stdout as such just overwrite the output it was just assigned?

Comment: @Peter Sorry I'm not getting it. It's been a long day at work I can't seem to process this

Comment: @coco the responseWriter implements io.Writer, much like a file, or pipe, or buffer does. By assigning `w` to `cmd.Stdout`, you are telling it 'Hey, pretend this is a file, or console, or anything at all that I can write to' and the `cmd` (in this case, the python) will write it there.

However, at the end of the day, I think @Peter is right that you need some fancier things like websockets to really do this

Comment: So like instead of the stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe() I'd just do cmd.Stdout = w, then what would I pass to go copyOutput? cmd.Stdout?

Comment: And I have a fully functioning website with multiple pages and a database connected to the frontend (written in angular) via the backend (in go)

Comment: I think I finally understand. I'm going to try it now

Comment: @coco You won't need `copyOutput` or a goroutine at all in theory. Again, though, this is going to behave differently depending on what you use to 'view' it. For instance, browsers strongly prefer to have the output stop and the request close at some point =)

Comment: So setting cmd.Stdout = w works, but it still only prints once the whole function is complete

Comment: True haha :) The real function I'm going to run here is going to take a long longer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic (naive) example but how can give you an idea of how to stream data continuously:

https://play.golang.org/p/vtXPEHSv-Sg

The code for `game.py` is:

```
import time
import sys

while True:
    print("Hello")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

The web app code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/nbari/violetear"
)

func stream(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("python", "game.py")
    rPipe, wPipe, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    cmd.Stdout = wPipe
    cmd.Stderr = wPipe
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    go writeOutput(w, rPipe)
    cmd.Wait()
    wPipe.Close()
}

func writeOutput(w http.ResponseWriter, input io.ReadCloser) {
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Streaming not supported", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Important to make it work in browsers
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    in := bufio.NewScanner(input)
    for in.Scan() {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n", in.Text())
        flusher.Flush()
    }
    input.Close()
}

func main() {
    router := violetear.New()
    router.HandleFunc("/", stream, "GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

The key part here is the use of [http.Flusher](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Flusher) and some headers to make it work within a browser:

```
 w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
```

Note the problem with this code is that once a request arrives it will `exec` the command that loops forever, so the `wPipe.Close()` will never be called

```
    cmd.Wait()
    wPipe.Close()
```

To be more verbose you could print the output the terminal beside the browser:

```
 for in.Scan() {
     data := in.Text()
     log.Printf("data: %s\n", data)
     fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n", data)
     flusher.Flush()
 }
```

If you have more than one request you will notice it will write faster in the terminal, not bad but you will also notice that if the client closed the connection/browser you will still see data going out.

A better way could execute the command within a context, from the example: https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 100*time.Millisecond)
defer cancel()

if err := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sleep", "5").Run(); err != nil {
    // This will fail after 100 milliseconds. The 5 second sleep
    // will be interrupted.
}
```

Also take a look at the context (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146619/1135424) not replaces `http.CloseNotifier` so could be usefull for terminate the process once the client close browser, disconetcs.

At the end depends on your needs but hope can give you an idea about how to stream data in an easy way by using the `http.Flusher` interface.

Just for fun here is an example using the [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/):

https://play.golang.org/p/V69BuDUceBA

Still very basic, but in this case if client closes the browser the program also terminates, as an exercice could be nice to improve it an share back ;-), notice the use of [CommandContext](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#CommandContext) and `ctx.Done()`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/nbari/violetear"
)

func stream(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    ch := make(chan struct{})

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "python", "game.py")
    rPipe, wPipe, err := os.Pipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    cmd.Stdout = wPipe
    cmd.Stderr = wPipe
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go writeOutput(w, rPipe)

    go func(ch chan struct{}) {
        cmd.Wait()
        wPipe.Close()
        ch <- struct{}{}
    }(ch)

    select {
    case <-ch:
    case <-ctx.Done():
        err := ctx.Err()
        log.Printf("Client disconnected: %s\n", err)
    }
}

func writeOutput(w http.ResponseWriter, input io.ReadCloser) {
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Streaming not supported", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Important to make it work in browsers
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")

    in := bufio.NewScanner(input)
    for in.Scan() {
        data := in.Text()
        log.Printf("data: %s\n", data)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %s\n", data)
        flusher.Flush()
    }
    input.Close()
}

func main() {
    router := violetear.New()
    router.HandleFunc("/", stream, "GET")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Comment: nbari, thank you for the detailed, complete example but even trying this example, I have not been able to get the web browser to show the commands as they run. It still locks up the browser until it's complete, even with the flusher and scan

Comment: @CocoBennett I tried with `curl` & `Chrome browser` just in case using `go version go1.10 darwin/amd64` if it helps